# Listing skills in CV. Good knowledge or good knowledge of?

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis, lists

I'm writing a CV in English and I want to list my skills. Should I write:

> Good knowledge:
>
> - X
> - Y
> - Z

or:

> Good knowledge of:
>
> - X
> - Y
> - Z

I know that a proper form is for example "I have knowledge of X" but I don't know which form is proper in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the second option, **Good Knowledge Of: ...** , sounds more natural.  It is not uncommon in formal or academic writing to write lists as though they were part of a complete sentence:

> I have good knowledge of X, Y, and Z.
> -----
> I have good knowedge of
>
> - X,
> - Y, and
> - Z.

Outside of academic writing, however, this often gets simplified into the form you used—removing the "I have" and extra punctuation and conjunctions. You can [go here](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/03/lists-part-5-bulleted-lists.html) to read more about bulleted lists (and there are a number of links to other articles on list styles at the bottom of the page).

In this context, it is also natural to see things like **Skilled with** or **Trained in** or **Good understanding of**; in American usage, **Proficient in** is fairly common. It just depends on how you want to present your capabilities.

---

The first option is possible, certainly grammatical, but "Good Knowledge" as a header feels unnatural to me.  It works in an introductory phrase ("Good Knowledge of") but not as a descriptive category ("Good Knowledge").

To keep that structure, try to pick a more specific noun, such as **Skills**, or **Qualifications**, or even just **Knowledge** (again, depends on how you want to present your skills).

Comment: For native English (at least the American version...) I'd use "Proficient in:" rather than "Gook knowledge." Proficient has the connotation that you could be productive immediately using X,Y and Z.

Comment: That does ring true—I've added it @MaxW